# React Starter Kit vs Next.js

Tags: javascript, isomorphic-javascript, server-side-rendering, react-starter-kit, next.js

We are looking into frameworks/libraries to build a content publishing site using React, key requirements are usual stuff  SEO, page speed, along with ease of server side rendering. Has anyone any experience with using [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) in production environment for a medium-large sized application? Has anyone tried [Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js)?

Am new to React kits and frameworks, and as I understand RSK is just an isomorphic boilerplate and next.js is also isomorphic though with server-side rendering. How do they compare and what might work in what situation? am not necessarily looking for an easy to put together boilerplate but a library/framework that has a strong base and can justify use in production.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried Nextjs and its working fine in production . Nextjs is easy to setup and gives you ssr functionality .It easier to create isomorphic app with Nextjs in comparison react kit.
With SSR page load is instant with Nextjs .

Comment: Thank for the response, am interested in "It easier to create isomorphic app with Nextjs in comparison react kit" have you used React starter kit before? How did you/your team come to this conclusion?

Comment: yes i have used react-starter kit before in another project you have to configure everything  according to you , but next its easy to configure as most of dependency handled by next itself.... and you know react is just a library so you need supporting packages with it ,even though you are using starter kit you should have knowledge that how different packages are linked . and making an app isomorphic in react  takes a lot of effort in comaprison to next.. And with next you can use all the knowledge you have in react without worrying about the dependency.